# How do I center an element on large display using materialize?

Tags: materialize

I am using Materialize CSS and I'm trying to center a div. I'm trying to get the white boxes to center on mobile and desktop to the center of the page. All the white boxes are in the same div called `root`.

index.html

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">

       <div id="mainContent" class="row">

          <div id="root" class="col s12 xl l6"></div>

       </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

styles.css

```
#mainContent {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#root {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

On mobile, it centers the white boxes correctly.
[image: On mobile, it centers the white boxes correctly.]

On desktop the boxes are on the left side.
[image: Desktop view]

If I add `margin-left` to `.root{}` then it's not centered on the mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a wrapper to index.html like so

```
<div id="mainContent" class="row">
    <div class="valign-wrapper">
        <div id="root" class="col s12 xl l6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the white boxes are centered in the middle on both smaller resoultion displays and bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [grid offsets](http://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-offsets) on the columns:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainContent" class="row">
            <div class="col s12 l6 offset-l3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Adding the class `offset-l3` will add an offset of 3 columns on the left for screen sizes `l` and `xl`. With 12 total columns and the content being 6 columns an offset of 3 will result in the content being centered.

The `style.css` can be updated to only set the `background-color`:

```
#mainContent {
    background-color: blue;
}
```